# How to fix: "TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating '$('div.comment').getLast')"

Tags: javascript, ios, mootools

Please who knows how fix this error? I'm trying to send my comment to the site server and get this error (I'm using mootools,framework: moobilejs)
mine javascript code here https://www.evernote.com/shard/s448/sh/a1d1bdd9-24be-430c-a06d-5c8c0bf8952b/8b89d559e705c2d2df17f57f5fb498eb
my html code
`

```
<div data-role="navigation-bar" class="center">
    <div data-role="button" data-name="back-button" data-style="back" class="bar-left">
        <div class="in_comment"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="title" class="bar-center">Коментарии</div>
    <div data-role="button" class="bar-right"> 
        <div class="best"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="activity-text" id="loader1">Загрузка</div>
    <div id="loader2" data-role="activity-indicator" data-name="activity-indicator" class="activity-indicator active"></div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: You should post your code in your question not as a link to another site. This is so the code can be preserved if that link ever dies.

Comment: You should use double dollar `$$` because single dollar in MooTools is alias for `document.id`. So do `$$('div.comment').getLast();`

Comment: and was first and there was another mistake, I was advised on this forum to fix one $ sign and the error appeared

Comment: I saw that wrong answer. I downvoted it and left a comment there so he will correct. Anyway, the main problem, as I wrote there, is that `$$('div.comment')` returns empty. Is there a `div`element with `class="comment"`? I will be around and check when you post your HTML

Comment: Sergio, i'm post my html code on topic

Comment: and I think that what that value should be in last(...)

Comment: @EvgenyDavidoff, I see no `div` element with `class="comment"`. But I do see a `class="in_comment"`.

Comment: @Sergio, I'm trying change it two days ago and it gave no results((

Comment: @EvgenyDavidoff did you understand my comment/question about the class names?

Comment: @EvgenyDavidoff: ping

Comment: @Sergio, I'm realized that the miss of a class comment leads to an error

Comment: @Sergio, did you ever something like that?  I'm mean service comments on your site or application?

Comment: @EvgenyDavidoff so did you fix the problem? Then you can delete this question. Yes, comments in the code are really useful. Makes it easy for others to work on it also.